# wsdl soap server not returning xml

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have to write soap wsdl server in php. 
Requirement:
request:two parameters say startDate & endDate
response: as follows

```
<students>   
     <student FirstName='Mr. A' LastName='B' />   
     <student FirstName='Mr. B' LastName='C' /> 
</students>
```

Can any one help me writing wsdl file & soap server for the above requirement. I tried many ways but failing for last 4 days.

Please help in writing WSDL file & SOAP Server which communicates with WSDL file, if possible a test client to verify.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: could you give a bit more detail, i.e. what attempts have you made, which libraries have you tried and what exactly isnt working with them.  this will increase the chances of a good answer...

Comment: I've written as Server class and set it through php's built-in soapserver class. 
`class Service{
   function getStudents($startDate, $endDate){
      return array("Students"=>array(array("FirstName"=>"Mr. A", "LastName"=>"B"), array("FirstName"=>"Mr. B', "LastName"=>"C")));
   }
 }

$server = new SoapServer('student.wsdl');
$server->setClass('Service);
$server->handle();`

student.wsdl is a common wsdl file with document type which i found at [link](http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL) and other tried thru eclipse plugin wsdl but those failed..

Comment: @munna: you have to create your own WSDL file! The WSDL file is specific to your web service and describes the service operations.

Comment: @ZombieHunter: problem is how to create wsdl file for above mentioned requirement.. I didn't find solution for it.... How can I define elements in wsdl for an associative array type of output..

Comment: @munna: Check the links in my updated answer or use Google to find some nice tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `SoapServer` class:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php

Keep in mind that this class is not always available:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/soap.installation.php

Using Google I found a few tutorials explaining how to set up a SOAP web service:

- http://devzone.zend.com/25/php-soap-extension/
- http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Web-Services-WSDL-Creating-SOAP-Server-P477.html

  > Please help in writing WSDL file & SOAP Server which communicates with
  >   WSDL file, if possible a test client to verify.

IMHO quite high expectations on a simple Q&A site...

Comment: please check the comment given above... and help me finding the working example which generates xml output with multiple tags with attributes.